# Mapping mouse position from full screen to smaller frame

Tags: c++, math, opengl, transform

I have been stuck on remapping my mouse position to a new frame for a few days and I am unsure what to do. I will provide images to describe my issue. The main problem is I want to click on an object in my program and the program will highlight the object I select (in 3d space.) I have this working perfectly when my application is in full screen mode. I recently started rendering my scene into a smaller frame so that I can have editor tools on the sides(like unity.) Here is the transition (graphically) i made from working to not working:

[image]

So essentially the mouse coordinates go from (0,0) to (screenWidth, screenHeight).. I want to map these coordinates to be from (frameStartX, frameStartY) to (frameStartX + frameWidth, frameStartY + frameHeight). I did some research on linearly transforming a number to scale it to a new range so I thought I could do this:

```
float frameMousePosX = (mousePosX - 0) / (screenWidth - 0) * ((frameWidth + frameStartX) - frameStartX ) + frameStartX ;
float frameMousePosY = (mousePosY - 0) / (screenHeight - 0) * ((frameHeight +frameStartY) - frameStartY ) + frameStartY;
```

I assumed this would work but it doesn't. It's not even close. I am really unsure what to do to get this transformation.

Assuming the transformation works, I would want it to read 0,0 at the bottom left of the frameStart which is (x,y) in the image attached and then reach its peak at the top right of the framed scene.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: The linear mapping looks good to me, could it be that one of the variables involved is incorrect (e.g. width / height swapped), or that the way you're testing this has another unrelated bug?

Comment: Depending on which method you are using to read the mouse position & width / height, another thing to look out for is pixel density (if you have a high-dpi screen).

Comment: Reading the question again, I would also double-check: are you trying to map coordinates from the small screen to the large one, or the other way around? It might just be that you've done the transformation in the opposite direction.

Comment: @merlinND I am trying to go from very big screen to one 1/3 the size roughly.  I will try the transform in the other direction when I get to my work computer!

Comment: @merlinND how would you suggest flipping the transformation? I am fairly sure I did it the correct way but if you suggest something else I could try.